# Using a numpy array to assign values to another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, vectorization

I have the following numpy array `matrix` ,

```
matrix = np.zeros((3,5), dtype = int)

array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Suppose I have this numpy array `indices` as well

```
indices = np.array([[1,3], [2,4], [0,4]])

array([[1, 3],
       [2, 4],
       [0, 4]])
```

**Question:** How can I assign `1`s to the elements in the `matrix` where their indices are specified by the `indices` array. A vectorized implementation is expected.

For more clarity, the output should look like:

```
    array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 0], #[1,3] elements are changed
           [0, 0, 1, 0, 1], #[2,4] elements are changed
           [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]]) #[0,4] elements are changed
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one approach using [`NumPy's fancy-indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing) -

```
matrix[np.arange(matrix.shape[0])[:,None],indices] = 1
```

**Explanation**

We create the row indices with `np.arange(matrix.shape[0])` -

```
In [16]: idx = np.arange(matrix.shape[0])

In [17]: idx
Out[17]: array([0, 1, 2])

In [18]: idx.shape
Out[18]: (3,)
```

The column indices are already given as `indices` -

```
In [19]: indices
Out[19]: 
array([[1, 3],
       [2, 4],
       [0, 4]])

In [20]: indices.shape
Out[20]: (3, 2)
```

Let's make a schematic diagram of the shapes of row and column indices, `idx` and `indices` -

```
idx     (row) :      3 
indices (col) :  3 x 2
```

For using the row and column indices for indexing into input array `matrix`, we need to make them broadcastable against each other. One way would be to introduce a new axis into `idx`, making it `2D` by pushing the elements into the first axis and allowing a singleton dim as the last axis with `idx[:,None]`, as shown below -

```
idx     (row) :  3 x 1
indices (col) :  3 x 2
```

Internally, `idx` would be broadcasted, like so -

```
In [22]: idx[:,None]
Out[22]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])

In [23]: indices
Out[23]: 
array([[1, 3],
       [2, 4],
       [0, 4]])

In [24]: np.repeat(idx[:,None],2,axis=1) # indices has length of 2 along cols
Out[24]: 
array([[0, 0],  # Internally broadcasting would be like this
       [1, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```

Thus, the broadcasted elements from `idx` would be used as row indices and column indices from `indices` for indexing into `matrix` for setting elements in it. Since, we had -

`idx = np.arange(matrix.shape[0])`,

Thus, we would end up with -

`matrix[np.arange(matrix.shape[0])[:,None],indices]` for setting elements.

Comment: I got my work accomplished with your approach but the implementation is somewhat blurry to me. Could you elaborate a little bit more on the operations performed?

Comment: @akilat90 See if the added comments make sense.

Answer (score 0):

this involves loop and hence may not be very efficient for large arrays

```
for i in range(len(indices)):
    matrix[i,indices[i]] = 1

> matrix
 Out[73]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
      [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```